# ImageTK.PhotoImage displays only light gray screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I am banging my head trying to get an ImageTK.PhotoImage to display properly.   I keep just getting a full-screen light-gray screen instead of the image.

I have tried this about 20 different iterations with functions inside classes, etc., but here is the current --now sufficiently mangled-- code:

*baseball.py*

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from game import Game
from menu import Menu
from display import ShowSplash
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Canvas
from PIL import Image, ImageTk



root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Baseball')
root.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')
root.geometry(str(root.winfo_screenwidth()) + 'x' + str(root.winfo_screenheight()) + '+0+0')    
root['background'] = '#000000'
canvas = Canvas(root, width = root.winfo_screenwidth(), height = root.winfo_screenheight())
canvas.pack()

ShowSplash(canvas)

root.mainloop()
```

and *display.py*

```py
import os
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class ShowSplash:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.image = Image.open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'images/splash-screen.jpg'))
        self.splashScreenImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='center', image=self.splashScreenImage)
        time.sleep(5)
```

Any ideas on how to get this working correctly?

Comment: Your image never gets displayed at all, you're just seeing the background color of the Canvas.  `time.sleep()` does not allow the display to be updated - and immediately after that ends, the `ShowSplash` instance goes out of scope, causing the image to be garbage-collected.  You need to save a reference to the instance, get rid of the `sleep`, and instead use `.after()` to do something 5 seconds later.

Comment: Shouldn't `.create_image(0, 0, anchor="center", ...)` actually be: `.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw")`?

Comment: @TheLizzard , I originally had "nw" but then changed it to "center" while debugging.  That is now changed back since it is now working!